# some weird signs appearing on SQL SERVER Query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

i have written a SELECT Query on SQL SERVER 2014 . I have got the desired output . but an apostrophe symbol(') appearing on 'TaskAction' field data(at the end of each data). here it is my script:

```
SELECT
  WOtask.PK,
  WOPK,
  TaskNo,
  TaskAction =
              CASE
                WHEN WOTask.AssetPK IS NOT NULL THEN '<b>' + Asset.AssetName + ' [' + Asset.AssetID + ']</b> ' + CASE
                    WHEN Asset.Vicinity IS NOT NULL AND
                      Asset.Vicinity <> '''' THEN RTRIM(Asset.Vicinity) + ': '
                    ELSE ''''
                  END + WOtask.TaskAction + CASE
                    WHEN CONVERT(varchar, ValueLow) IS NOT NULL AND
                      CONVERT(varchar, ValueHi) IS NOT NULL AND
                      Spec = 1 THEN ' (Range: '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(ValueLow,0))) + '' - '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(ValueHi,0))) + )'
                    ELSE ''''
                  END
                ELSE WOtask.TaskAction + CASE
                    WHEN CONVERT(varchar, ValueLow) IS NOT NULL AND
                      CONVERT(varchar, ValueHi) IS NOT NULL AND
                      Spec = 1 THEN ' (Range: '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(ValueLow,0))) + '' - '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(ValueHi,0))) + )'
                    ELSE ''''
                  END
              END,
  Rate,
  Measurement,
  Initials,
  Fail,
  Complete,
  Header,
  LineStyle,
  WOtask.Comments,
  WOtask.NotApplicable,
  WOTask.Photo1,
  WOTask.Photo2
FROM WOtask WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON Asset.AssetPK = WOTask.AssetPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetSpecification
  ON AssetSpecification.PK = WOTask.AssetSpecificationPK
WHERE (WOPK IN (SELECT
  WOPK
FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
)
ORDER BY WOPK, TaskNo
```

now please check my output and error 
[image]

please help to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you using `ELSE ''''` instead of `ELSE ''`?

Comment: Your have loads of `ELSE ''''` in your `CASE` expressions. Try `SELECT ''''`. it'll return the string `'`. I **assume** you mean `ELSE ''`?

Comment: thank you sir for pick the error . yes i agree with you i should write the ELSE ' ' instead of ELSE ' ' ' ' 
Problem is now solved . thanks once again .@MartinSmith

Comment: Off-topic: `'<b>' + Asset.AssetName` smells like a XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, use `ELSE ''` instead of `ELSE ''''`. The reason is that within a pair of single quotes, then `''` tells SQL to escape a single quote into your output.

For instance, to show the output `User's`, you would need `SELECT 'User''s'`.